# How to know the maximum of ships we can place in a table

Tags: algorithm, math, formula

I'm coding the battleship game for my programming class and I'm stuck at the part in which the user has to write the number of ships that they have to find. The problem is you cannot have a neighbour with each ship, not even diagonally. In addition, the program places the ships randomly and the teacher can change the number of rows and columns. So, I need to make a formula to determine how many ships I can place in a matrix. It also depends on where you place your ships (like the example in the picture).

[image]

Thank you.

P.S.: Ships occupy only one block.

Comment: Size of the ships?

Comment: This is off-topic since to related to some *existing* code and is not related to C (you'll have the same issue in some other programming language, like Common Lisp, C++, Python, Ocaml).... However, you don't need a formula to compute that number: you could place randomly new boats till you cannot place anymore a new one. You don't need any explicit formula (which perhaps might not even exist)

Comment: However, you could reason on a black&white board. Then an upper bound (for the number of ships) might be the number of black cells. For your next question  on SO, please provide an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

As your picture shows, the most ships you can have is 1 per 2x2 block. If any size is odd, you can have one more. So, the formula for maximum number is:

```
((width + 1) / 2) * ((height + 1) / 2)
```

If the ships have to be placed randomly, you will likely hit a noticably smaller number, but that's the maximum.